# Increment counts of sites visited including TLDs and subdomains outputted to JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, function

So I was asked to create an algorithm that when given a basic input of an array of counts and sites, it will output the accumulated visits to each TLD and Subdomain represented in a JSON object that will yield data like:

```
   1120   com
   800    google.com
   310    reddit.com
   60     mail.yahoo.com
   10     mobile.sports.yahoo.com
   50     sports.yahoo.com
   10     stackoverflow.com
   3      org
   3      wikipedia.org
   2      en.wikipedia.org
   2      es.wikipedia.org
   1      mobile.sports
   1      sports
```

The input is something like:

```
// visits = [ "800,google.com",
//       "60,mail.yahoo.com",
//       "10,mobile.sports.yahoo.com",
//       "40,sports.yahoo.com",
//       "310,reddit.com",
//       "10,stackoverflow.com",
//       "2,en.wikipedia.org",
//       "1,es.wikipedia.org",
//       "1,mobile.sports" ]
```

My code looks like this so far and I know its wrong, but my brain is melted at the moment and I am not sure how to proceed. I am not necessarily looking for you to write the algorithm for me, but I do want to understand logically how I could break this down.

```
function getDomainHits(arr){

  var splitCount = [];
  var splitDomains = [];
  var domainCountDict = {"Domains" : [],"Count" : 0};

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){

    splitCount = arr[i].split(",");

    splitDomains = splitCount[1].split(".");


      for (var j = 0; j < splitDomains.length; j++){


        if (!domainCountDict.Domain.includes(splitDomains[j])){

          domainCountDict.Domain.push(splitDomains[j]);

        }
      }

  }

  console.log(domainCountDict);
}
```

As you can see I stopped here because I couldn't think of the best way to split these into different key, value pairs - one being domains and the other being the counts. Also my algorithm doesn't exactly follow the requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out the algorithm. Define a variable - initialize it as an Array, and a dictionary to store the processed array data.

```
var splitCount = [];
var domainCountDict = {};
```

Then you need to take the Array of strings (arr - the function parameter) and iterate through it. On each iteration you need to split the string element into another Array to further process it.

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){

    splitCount = arr[i].split(",");
...
}
```

So for the example input data of

```
// visits = [ "800,google.com",
//       "60,mail.yahoo.com",
//       "10,mobile.sports.yahoo.com",
//       "40,sports.yahoo.com",
//       "310,reddit.com",
//       "10,stackoverflow.com",
//       "2,en.wikipedia.org",
//       "1,es.wikipedia.org",
//       "1,mobile.sports" ]
```

Iteration 0 would be split into an Array of ["800","google.com"] and assigned to Var splitCount. You would then need to access splitCount and because of the input formatting you don't need to create a for loop. I created a variable to store the current count of the site - which will always be element 0 because of the format of the input data.

I didn't bother with input sanitation here because I didn't have time to create a map function that will turn the number elements into - well... numbers. I relied on the assumption that the input data will always have a number in the 0th index - which is terrible. Don't do this.

```
var curCnt = 0;
  if (splitCount[0]){

    curCnt = splitCount[0];

  }
```

This next chunk of logic hurt my brain a little bit because I needed to find a way to store each domain component and its count in the dict and determine if the other domains contained components that already existed and if so increment those. Lets make some more Arrays!

```
var domain = [];
var currentDom = [];
      if (splitCount[1] != undefined && splitCount[1]){

        domain = splitCount[1].split(".");


        for (var j = domain.length - 1; j >= 0; j--){
         ...
        }
       }
```

Above you will see that created an Array to hold the domain components called domain and another called currentDom to hold the components that are being worked and have already been worked, because we want to make sure that we count com and google.com. Lets look inside of the for loop.

```
    for (var j = domain.length - 1; j >= 0; j--){


       currentDom.unshift(domain.pop());

       /*console.log("current iter: " + k + "\n"
                   + "currentDom: " + currentDom.join(".") + "\n"
                   + "current count: " + curCnt + "\n");*/

      if (currentDom.join(".") in domainCountDict){
        /*console.log("currentDom2: " + currentDom.join("."));
        console.log("increment existing");*/
        domainCountDict[currentDom.join(".")] += parseInt(curCnt);  


      }
      if (!(currentDom.join(".") in domainCountDict)){
        /*console.log("currentDom3: " + currentDom.join("."));
        console.log("increment new");*/
        domainCountDict[currentDom.join(".")] = parseInt(curCnt);


        //console.log(domainCountDict);
      }

    }
```

Above you will see that I am iterating backwards in this loop to work the TLD first and then the domains/subdomains. I chose to pop the last element off the end of the current array and unshift it to the beginning of the new Array, currentDom. This will effectively let me work on a portion of the entire FQDN to determine if it has been included in the dictionary.

I have a few if statements to determine if the currentDom is included in the array. I had to use Array.join() to accurately check if the string of the current domain components have been included in the dictionary. If not then the string of currentDom would be added as a key and the curCnt would be the value assigned. If so, then the value would be incremented. Because of my lazy input sanitation in the curCnt assignment I had to parse these as Int because JS dynamic types. I am sure there is a better way, but my brain hurts now.

Finally make sure that you return the created dictionary on the outside of all of these for loops.

The full algorithm is below

```
// Sample output (in any order/format):
// getTotalsByDomain(counts)
//   1320    com
//   900    google.com
//   410    yahoo.com
//    60    mail.yahoo.com
//    10    mobile.sports.yahoo.com
//    50    sports.yahoo.com
//    10    stackoverflow.com
//     3  org
//     3  wikipedia.org
//     2  en.wikipedia.org
//     1  es.wikipedia.org
//     1  mobile.sports
//   1  sports

let counts = [ "900,google.com",
    "60,mail.yahoo.com", 
    "10,mobile.sports.yahoo.com", 
    "40,sports.yahoo.com", 
    "300,yahoo.com", 
    "10,stackoverflow.com", 
    "2,en.wikipedia.org", 
    "1,es.wikipedia.org", 
    "1,mobile.sports" ];

console.log(getDomainHits(counts));

function getDomainHits(arr){

  var splitCount = [];
  var domainCountDict = {};

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){

    splitCount = arr[i].split(",");



    var curCnt = 0;
          if (splitCount[0]){

            curCnt = splitCount[0];

          }

    var domain = [];
    var currentDom = [];
          if (splitCount[1] != undefined && splitCount[1]){

            domain = splitCount[1].split(".");


            for (var j = domain.length - 1; j >= 0; j--){


               currentDom.unshift(domain.pop());

               /*console.log("current iter: " + k + "\n"
                           + "currentDom: " + currentDom.join(".") + "\n"
                           + "current count: " + curCnt + "\n");*/

              if (currentDom.join(".") in domainCountDict){
                /*console.log("currentDom2: " + currentDom.join("."));
                console.log("increment existing");*/
                domainCountDict[currentDom.join(".")] += parseInt(curCnt);  


              }
              if (!(currentDom.join(".") in domainCountDict)){
                /*console.log("currentDom3: " + currentDom.join("."));
                console.log("increment new");*/
                domainCountDict[currentDom.join(".")] = parseInt(curCnt);


                //console.log(domainCountDict);
              }

            }

          }

  }

  return domainCountDict;

}
```